Facing Issue while making the soap web client using spring web services
So this is one soap API I want to call:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
however this is the response I get from the API but still I want to write the generic code so that any soap APIs can be called.
This is how I have created the request class
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "RetrievePCData", namespace = "http://apcc.com/")
public class RetrievePCDataRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "sSalesOrderNo", namespace = "http://apcc.com/")
    private String salesOrderNo;

    public RetrievePCDataRequest() {
    }

    public RetrievePCDataRequest(String salesOrderNo) {
        this.salesOrderNo = salesOrderNo;
    }

    public String getSalesOrderNo() {
        return salesOrderNo;
    }

    public void setSalesOrderNo(String salesOrderNo) {
        this.salesOrderNo = salesOrderNo;
    }
}

This is how I am making the soap call:
 public Mono<String> retrievePCData(String salesOrderNo) {
               try {
                   RetrievePCDataRequest retrievePCDataRequest = new RetrievePCDataRequest();
                   retrievePCDataRequest.setSalesOrderNo(salesOrderNo);
                   String soapRequest = marshallSoapRequest(retrievePCDataRequest);
                   logger.info(soapRequest);
                   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                   headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE);
                   headers.add("SOAPAction", "http://apcc.com/RetrievePCData");
                   return webClientService.postXml("http://webservices.apc.com/webservices/apcbusinesssvc/ApcBusinessSvc.asmx", 
                           String.class, headers, soapRequest)
                           .doOnSuccess(response -> {
                               logger.info( response);
                               System.out.println( response);
                           })
                           .doOnError(error -> {
                               logger.error( error.getMessage(), error);
                               System.out.println("SOAP API Error: " + error.getMessage()); 
                           });
               } catch (JAXBException e) {
                   logger.error("Error while marshalling SOAP request", e);
                   return Mono.error(e);
               }
            
               
           }
           private String marshallSoapRequest(RetrievePCDataRequest request) throws JAXBException {
               SoapEnvelope envelope = new SoapEnvelope();
               SoapBody body = new SoapBody();
               body.setRequest(request);
               envelope.setBody(body);
               JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(SoapEnvelope.class);
               Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
               StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
               marshaller.marshal(envelope, writer);
               return writer.toString().replace("ns2:", "soap:").replace("xmlns:ns2", "xmlns:soap");
           }
    ```    
           
           and in the webclientservice this is how making the call


public  Mono postXml(String uri, Class responseType, HttpHeaders headers, String xmlBody) {
this.appLogger.info(EXTERNAL_API_POST_CALL_STARTED_MSG + uri);
    try {
    System.out.println(webClient.post()
               .uri("http://webservices.apc.com/webservices/apcbusinesssvc/ApcBusinessSvc.asmx")
               .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers))
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
               .bodyValue(xmlBody)
               .retrieve()
               .bodyToMono(String.class) // response body
               .block());}
    
    
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }



But The error message is not similar to the one which I have added as the screenshot of Soap Ui.
For reference I am sharing the xml that gets generated

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns3:Envelope xmlns="http://apcc.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><ns3:Body><RetrievePCData><sSalesOrderNo>652001379</sSalesOrderNo></RetrievePCData></ns3:Body></ns3:Envelope>

Can you please guide me 
   


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/DahGXjy4.png

